# Vertical CSS / jQuery Dropdown menu issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

In my web app I have a vertical CSS menu, to show it. My code works as expected, with one issue, when I mouse out on all `a.menutoggle` elements the last dropdown remains open.

I am not getting a clue on how to hide that? Please help!

```js
$('.menutoggle').mouseover(function(event) {
  $('.menucontainer').hide();
  $(this).next('.menucontainer').toggle();
});

$('#menutoggle').mouseout(function() {
  $('.menucontainer').hide();
});
```

```css
#menuwrap {
  padding: 50px;
}

.menutoggle {
  display: block;
  z-index: 99;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.menucontainer {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
  top: 50px;
  z-index: 999;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menuwrap">
  <a href="#" class="menutoggle">Menu Toggle</a>
  <ul class="menucontainer">
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" class="menutoggle">Menu Toggle</a>
  <ul class="menucontainer">
    <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Five</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Siz</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" class="menutoggle">Menu Toggle</a>
  <ul class="menucontainer">
    <li><a href="#">Seven</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Eight</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nine</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I've created a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/rz3g78h1/1/

Comment: That is the problem, it already made app and senior is asking not to change anything. And I had commented `'.menutoggle' hide mouseout` event knowingly because I tried that and when I enable it, it doesn't go away, instead the hovering on a link behaves differently and dropdown menu which is opened for one element doesn't stay. You can enable it and check the behaviour, which behaves wrong.

Comment: I added an answer for you below as I noticed that fixing your typo raises another issue in the logic.

Comment: Thanks, checking it by modifying my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary issue is because your `#menutoggle` selector on the `mouseout` event needs to use a class selector, not an id. Change it to `.menutoggle`.

However this raises another issue where the menu rapidly flickers as the mouse moves between the elements due to the use of `mouseout`. To fix this you can amend the logic to use CSS alone to show/hide the submenus, like this:

```css
#menuwrap {
  padding: 50px;
}

.menutoggle {
  display: block;
  z-index: 99;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.menucontainer {
  display: none;
}

.menutoggle:hover + .menucontainer,
.menutoggle + .menucontainer:hover {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
  top: 50px;
  z-index: 999;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: #999;
}
```

```html
<div id="menuwrap">
  <a href="#" class="menutoggle">Menu Toggle</a>
  <ul class="menucontainer">
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" class="menutoggle">Menu Toggle</a>
  <ul class="menucontainer">
    <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Five</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Siz</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" class="menutoggle">Menu Toggle</a>
  <ul class="menucontainer">
    <li><a href="#">Seven</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Eight</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nine</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```